# Camel Route For All Xml Files With Done File

Tags: java, apache-camel

I want to do a seemingly simple task with Apache Camel.  I want to monitor a directory for xml files.  When those xml files are found, if there is a corresponding done file with the same name, then I want camel to notify me.

Here's the route I'm using

```
from("file:/tmp?include=.*.xml&doneFileName=${file:name}.done")
```

but it doesn't trigger.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just to be sure you use &amp; to separate the options? This is required when using XML.

Comment: @ClausIbsen i am using a single ampersand character as shown above as opposed to a multi-character code for an ampersand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any issue with the route.
Check with something like

```
from("file:/tmp?include=.*.xml&doneFileName=${file:name}.done")
     .process(
    new Processor() {
         public void process(Exchange e) throws Exception{
        //Any logic or System.out.println("File is "+e.getIn().getBody());
         }
        });
```

Are you sure the file name matches the pattern?
How are you triggering the notification. Are you sure that code is fine or integrated well with this route.

Comment: hmm, don't know what was wrong before, but it seems to be triggering now.  thanks!